# numpy scipy python import sparse matrix from csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

i have a .csv file formatted like this:

`id_A,id_B
 2135,1
 2303,1
 6292,1`

with around 180k entry that rappresent the position in wich the matrix have a 1(the other value are 0) in a sparse matrix.
I was wondering if there is a way to import this in python with numpy or scipy.

Thanks

---

I try something like that and seems working

```
with open('icm.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    list = list(reader)
row = [] #i[:] the row indices of the matrix entries
coloumn = [] #[:] the column indices of the matrix entries
data=[] #data[:] the entries of the matrix, in any order
for i in range(1,len(list)):
    row.append(int(list[i][0]))
    coloumn.append(int(list[i][1]))
    data.append(1)
matrix = coo_matrix((data, (coloumn, row)))
```

Comment: So id_A is the row, and id_B is the column of the sparse matrix?

Comment: Looks like a mix of `.` and `,` delimiters?  That complictes reading the file.  In any case you need to load 3 columns of data, and use the `coo` format to construct the sparse matrix.

Comment: yes id_A is the row and id_B is the coloumn, the file format as been given to us and we can't modify. I edited the set, should be more clear the format now

Answer (score 0):

Make a sample 'file' from your sample:

```
In [47]: txt=b"""id_A,id_B
 2135,1
 2303,1
 6292,1"""
```

load it with `genfromtxt`; result is a structured array with 2 fields ('columns'):

```
In [48]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),
   names=True, dtype=None, delimiter=',')
In [49]: data
Out[49]: 
array([(2135, 1), (2303, 1), (6292, 1)], 
      dtype=[('id_A', '<i4'), ('id_B', '<i4')])
In [50]: data['id_A']
Out[50]: array([2135, 2303, 6292])
```

Create a `coo` format matrix from that data:

```
In [51]: from scipy import sparse
In [52]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(data['id_A']),
             (data['id_A'],data['id_B'])))
In [53]: M
Out[53]: 
<6293x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [54]: M.row
Out[54]: array([2135, 2303, 6292], dtype=int32)
In [55]: M.col
Out[55]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [56]: M.data
Out[56]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: `recfromcsv` is a shortcut for the options you pass to `genfromtxt` here.